# How to get the color of a pixel in an UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

The color circle can rotate, when the circle rotate, and I want to get the color at triangle of the color circle，I used the method :

```
- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

[self.layer renderInContext:context];

CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

//NSLog(@"pixel: %d %d %d %d", pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[3]);

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 green:pixel[1]/255.0 blue:pixel[2]/255.0 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

return color;
}
```

But It not get the correct color when circle rotate, I all code is on the github: 
https://github.com/carya/GetViewColor   , can any one help me to fix this bug, thanks so much.

[image]

PS: I have test the - (UIColor *)colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point  method is right at normal view, but in my code, the result looks strange.

---

Update:

Finally I fixed this problem and post an article to explain this, you can reach at [this](http://liumh.com/2015/07/26/ios-get-color-of-uiview/)

Comment: How are you creating that colour circle?

Comment: @Fogmeister, I Use UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer to created the color circle, you can see the code in class of DrawCircus at https://github.com/carya/GetViewColor/blob/master/GetViewColor/DrawCircus.m  , please help me to fix this problem, thanks.

Comment: Ah, it's from an image. Thought you might have been drawing the blue and yellow.

Comment: @Fogmeister, using image is easier to implement the same effect, drawing with code will do more work. What's wrong with my code, I have do much work to fix, but still not fixed it.

Comment: I haven't found specifically how yet but you can get the byte data from an image. Groups of bytes then represent each pixel. So you can move along the bytes to find the pixel you are after. Then the byte information will hold the RGBA values which will give you the colour. I'll keep looking but that's the gist.

Comment: @Fogmeister，I'll try to implement follow you suggestion, thanks so much